# Swagger GET POST redirects to wrong path during GET call in UI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

need help related to Swagger Controller in DotnetCore C#

Here is the controller config for Swagger.

```
    [ApiVersion("1")]    
    [Route("/DCSapi/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DCSSampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly string _version = "v1";

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/DCSapi/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/health")]
        public IActionResult HealthProbe()
        {
            // return 200
            return Ok($"DCS Sample - HealthProbe - {_version} IP Address = {DcsNet.GetLocalIpAddress()} Environment.MachineName = {Environment.MachineName}");
        }
```

Swagger is running at - [www.somehostname.com/sample-dcs/index.html](http://www.somehostname.com/sample-dcs/index.html)

When I click on GET and try to execute,
curl is making a call to below, and getting 404.

```
somehostname.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/DCSapi/v1/DCSOrders/health
```

[image]

But CURL should point to this below URL, since Swagger is running at [www.somehostname.com/sample-dcs](http://www.somehostname.com/sample-dcs)

```
somehostname.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/sample-dcs/DCSapi/v1/DCSOrders/health
```

sample-dcs might be changed in future.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with .NET or Swagger. You seem to be hitting an Azure API Gateway that is redirecting the request

Comment: first or all you don't have to specify route on each method. Once you declare at the beginning of the file, you don't have to do it at this method for example: ```public IActionResult HealthProbe()``` just put ```[Route("/health")]``` , and the method should work.

Comment: Can you show Startup? Notably the Swagger and MVC part.

Comment: Hi Sarxha - I tried that, but no luck.

Comment: Hi Vernou - here it is:

```
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Rpe.Delivers.DCS.Order");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
```